# Rxjs Returns first result of two observables run sequentially

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, sequential

I need to run sequentially two observables and returns the result of the first observable only. The second observable needs the first to be completed before running.

I found a workaround but I'm not satisfied. You can test it here : [plunker test](https://plnkr.co/edit/PoDQhfXiXTWbB1qbAmWx?p=catalogue)

```
const first = Observable.of(10).delay(1000).do(res => console.log('first'));
const second = Observable.of(20).do(res => console.log('second'));
console.log('start');
const test = first.concatMap(ev => second.map(x=> ev)).subscribe(res => 
console.log(res));
```

I think (and I hope !) a nicer solution exists but I can't find it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't think there's any better way to do this. The only improvement could be using `ev => second.mapTo(ev)` to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I internally translate `flatMap` to `then` in my head so I would expect to see something like...

```
const first = Observable.of(10).delay(1000).do(res => console.log('first'));
const second = Observable.of(20).do(res => console.log('second'));
const test = first.flatMap(rsp => { return second.mapTo(rsp); });
```

It isn't really any different than what you posted but it would make more sense to me intuitively since I wouldn't start thinking about the `concat` operation.

Update:

I suppose you could also do...

```
const test = first.delayWhen(() => second.mapTo(0));
```

...but I'm not sure if that is more readable.

Comment: the two entries work but I would like something cleaner than `second.mapTo`

Comment: You could always write your own operator or static function.  Call it bufferUntil or delayUntil or something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think you could use [concatMapTo](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmapto.html). See Example 2.
In your case:

```
const first$ = of(10).pipe(delay(1000),tap(res => console.log('first')));
const second$ = of(20).pipe(tap(res => console.log('second')));

const test = first$.pipe(
  concatMapTo(
    second$,
    (first, second) => first
  )
);
test.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xrmsy5

If you want to manage more observables you could use switchMap/mergeMap. For example

```
const test = first$.pipe(
  // map(e => { if(e === '1') throw e; return e; } ), //throwing invalid result
  switchMap(e => second$, (f,s) => {console.log('switchMap',f,s); return f;}),
  switchMap(e => trird$, (f,s) => {console.log('switchMap', f,s); return f;}),
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mnsd8a

Answer (score 0):

User `merge` with `take(1)`:

```typescipt
Observable.merge(first, second).take(1).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Comment: It returns the second result only. It's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = first
    .pipe(
        delayWhen(() => second)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
        ...
    });
```

This should execute both the first and second observables in order but only emit the result of the first observable after the result from the second observable is emitted internally.